# Polymorphic filter iterator range

Tags: c++, boost, iterator

I have a sequence of elements (usually a `std::vector<T>`), and a method `overlap_range(Iterator, Iterator, T)` for obtaining a subset of these elements that are `overlap`ed with `T`.

If the sequence of elements satisfy certain criteria, then the result of `overlap_range` will be contiguous, and determinable in logarithmic time. Otherwise there may be multiple discontiguous such sub-ranges, which can only be determined in linear time. It takes linear time to determine if the criteria are satisfied.

I would like the following:

1. `overlap_range` to be polymorphic, in the sense that the algorithm operates in logarithmic time if the criteria are known to be satisfied.
2. The returned sub-range is polymorphic, to be able to take advantage of the known properties of the sub-range if the criteria are satisfied.

My proposed solution was to use a default valued flag parameter in `overlap_range`, this takes care of (1). I then thought to solve (2) by using a `boost::filter_iterator<std::function<bool(T)>, Iterator>` where the `std::function<bool(T)>` simply returns `true` if the criteria are known to be satisfied. However, this turned out to be approx. 50x slower than simply using a functor to test for `overlap`ed in both cases. The logic for `overlap` is not particularly complex, but the number of elements in the range is sufficiently large for there to be a significant advantage to not having to evaluate it unnecessarily, if possible.

Are there any other approaches that might help me solve this problem?

**More details**

Although I think the above is sufficient to understand the problem, here is some more background that could be useful.

- `T` is any object that can be reduced to a `GenomicRegion`, that simply defines a set of co-ordinates on a single contiguous sequence (i.e. two co-ordinates). Any such `T` is actually a `Mappable<T>` which basically requires a method `get_region`.
- `overlaps` is then defined as

  ```
  inline GenomicRegion::DifferenceType overlap_size(const GenomicRegion& lhs, const GenomicRegion& rhs) noexcept
  {
      return static_cast< GenomicRegion::DifferenceType>(std::min(lhs.get_end(), rhs.get_end())) -
              static_cast< GenomicRegion::DifferenceType>(std::max(lhs.get_begin(), rhs.get_begin()));
  }

  inline bool overlaps(const GenomicRegion& lhs, const GenomicRegion& rhs) noexcept
  {
      auto num_bases_overlaped = overlap_size(lhs, rhs);
      return (num_bases_overlaped == 0) ? !are_adjacent(lhs, rhs) || empty(std::min(lhs, rhs)) : num_bases_overlaped > 0;
  }
  ```
- Any `Mappable` class can be sorted by the begin co-ordinate, and then the end co-ordinate (if begin co-ordinates are equal).
- The "criteria" for logarithmic overlap searching (and contiguous resulting region), is that: if `a <= b` then `end(a) <= end(b)`, this would be true if for example all `T` were the same size.
- The naive filter iterator is defined as

  ```
  template <typename MappableType>
  class IsOverlapped
  {
  public:
      IsOverlapped() = delete;
      template <typename MappableType_>
      IsOverlapped(const MappableType_& mappable) : region_ {get_region(mappable)} {}
      bool operator()(const MappableType& mappable) { return overlaps(mappable, region_); }
  private:
      GenomicRegion region_;
  };

  template <typename Iterator>
  using OverlapIterator = boost::filter_iterator<IsOverlapped<typename Iterator::value_type>, Iterator>;

  template <typename Iterator>
  using OverlapRange = boost::iterator_range<OverlapIterator<Iterator>>;
  ```
- `overlap_range` can then be declared as

  ```
  template <typename ForwardIterator, typename MappableType>
  OverlapRange<ForwardIterator>
  overlap_range(ForwardIterator first, ForwardIterator last, const MappableType& mappable, bool is_bidirectional=false)
  ```

Of course, this could simply return the range `OverlapRange<ForwardIterator>(first, last)`, but we can do a lot better than this by efficiently finding the right bound, and also the left bound if the range `is_bidirectional`.

Answer (score 0):

The biggest slow down was likely because of the dynamic dispatch in `std::function<>`. You could try to replace that with a custom, non-type-erased predicate type (function object?).

---

I should probably be asking what it means for the elements in a range to *"be `overlapped` with `T`"*.
Maps of Numbers which will be called Quantifiers
But, let me just jump to a bit of conclusion because it is a good excuse to show off Boost Interval Container library.

Note the demo hinges on the fact that Boost ICL has builtin [Combining Styles](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/icl/doc/html/index.html#boost_icl.introduction.interval_combining_styles) and Comparers for many things. From the docs for the [Map concept](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/icl/doc/html/boost_icl/semantics/maps.html):

> - **Maps of Sets** that will be called **Collectors** and
> - **Maps of Numbers** which will be called **Quantifiers**

For a good sense of what it implemented out-of-the-box I chose to demo with `Collector`s, i.e. `T` in your terminology happens to be `std::set<int>`.

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/847658c3b730715e)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/icl/interval_map.hpp>
#include <set>

namespace icl = boost::icl;

using Container = icl::interval_map<
    size_t,          // mirrors the vector index
    std::set<int> >; // set intersection models our "overlap"

Container generate_random_data();

#include <iostream>

int main() {
    auto haystack = generate_random_data();

    // let's find all ranges where the T overlaps with -2:

    using Seive = Container::value_type;

    std::cout << "Haystack: " << haystack << "\n";
    std::cout << "Overlaps -2: \n\t-> " << (haystack & Seive {{ 0, 1024 }, { -2 }}) << "\n";
    std::cout << "Overlaps +7: \n\t-> " << (haystack & Seive {{ 0, 1024 }, { +7 }}) << "\n";

    // you can even do a "multi-sieve" in one pass:
    std::cout << "Overlaps any of +7 or -2: \n\t-> " << (haystack & Seive {{ 0, 1024 }, { -2, +7 }}) << "\n";

    // and more interesting, you can narrow any of the "overlap" targets to a certain input range:
    Container combined;
    combined += Seive {{ 128, 512 }, { -2 }};
    combined += Seive {{ 512, 768 }, { +7 }};
    std::cout << "Complex query " << combined << ": \n\t-> " << (haystack & combined) << "\n";
}

#include <random>
#include <functional>

Container generate_random_data() {
    using namespace std;

    mt19937 prng {random_device{}()};
    // mt19937 prng {3236629322};
    auto card     = bind(uniform_int_distribution<>(1,       5),    ref(prng));
    auto domain   = bind(uniform_int_distribution<size_t>(0, 1024), ref(prng));
    auto codomain = bind(uniform_int_distribution<>(-10,     10),   ref(prng));
    auto gen_val  = [&] { 
        Container::value_type::second_type v;
        generate_n(inserter(v, end(v)), card(), codomain);
        return v;
    };

    auto gen_range = [&]() -> Container::value_type { 
        auto left = domain(), right = domain();
        if (left>right) swap(left, right);

        return { 
            Container::interval_type::right_open ( left, right ),
            gen_val()
        };
    };

    {
        Container data;
        generate_n(icl::inserter(data, end(data)), prng() % 1024, gen_range);
        return data;
    }
}
```

Which prints (for the particular seed)

```
Haystack: {([0,1)->{-10 3 })([1,5)->{-10 })([5,13)->{-9 -1 3 7 10 })([13,17)->{-4 1 6 10 })([17,69)->{0 2 4 8 })([69,81)->{-7 -4 9 })([81,97)->{1 8 10 })([97,102)->{6 })([102,701)->{-10 -2 1 3 7 })([701,987)->{3 })([987,1002)->{-9 6 7 8 10 })([1002,1003)->{2 3 4 5 9 })([1003,1004)->{-9 -7 3 9 })([1004,1024)->{-10 -2 2 5 })}
Overlaps -2: 
    -> {([102,701)->{-2 })([1004,1024)->{-2 })}
Overlaps +7: 
    -> {([5,13)->{7 })([102,701)->{7 })([987,1002)->{7 })}
Overlaps any of +7 or -2: 
    -> {([5,13)->{7 })([102,701)->{-2 7 })([987,1002)->{7 })([1004,1024)->{-2 })}
Complex query {([128,512)->{-2 })([512,768)->{7 })}: 
    -> {([128,512)->{-2 })([512,701)->{7 })}
```

You can run the sample some more times to see the results with other randomly generated data sets.

Comment: Added the live sample. [live coding session](https://www.livecoding.tv/video/querying-interval-maps-wrandom-data-demo/) still available.

Comment: By "non-type-erased predicate type" do you mean simply conditioning on the predicate within the function object? I suppose this is the best I can hope for. The ICL looks like a nice library.. I'll be interested to see how it deals with my data.

Comment: Yes. You didn't show the function object, so I couldn't show it

Comment: I've added more (probably unnecessary) details about the problem.